# Validation for dates using validation controls? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.net web application, i am trying to validate the date that date should not be future date, today and past date only, using validation controls, can you help me, i tried for javascript and it is working fine but i wnat using validation controls. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) then in the [`ServerValidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event I would do the following:

```
protected void vldCustStartDate_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
   DateTime startDate;

   if (DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out startDate))
   {
       args.IsValid = startDate <= DateTime.Now;
   }
   else
   {
       args.IsValid = false;
   }
}
```